# Can I add one more condition to canExecute predicate?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, predicate, canexecute

I am using Josh Smith's RelayCommand in my WPF MVVM application.

I have a ViewModel. Inside that I have a reference to another ViewModel.

The child ViewModel has a property of type ICommand in it.

In my parent ViewModel, can I add one more condition to the "CanExecute" predicate?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two choices:

1. You can expose a new ICommand from the parent viewmodel that uses the child viewmodel in its implementation of CanExecute of the new command.
2. You can add a reference to the parent viewmodel in the child and call a method on the parent in the child's implementation of CanExecute.

The second option might look something like this in the child:

```
SampleCommand = new RelayCommand(..., param => ChildSampleCanExecute() && parentViewModel.ParentSampleCanExecute());
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can assign true/false to chldViwmodel's CanExecute from parent viewmodel ?...Or..Can I add one more condition to the child viewmodel's can execute preducate from parent viewmodel ?